# Decompose even graph in minimum and maximum cycles

Tags: graph, graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

Is there an algorithm that can decompose a simple undirected graph (with all vertices having even degrees) into maximum and minimum amount of cycles?

I know that it **can** be decomposed into cycles because it has even degrees in every vertex, but is there a way to find what is the minimum and maximum amount of possible cycles in a decomposition?

Comment: Interesting question! This would probably have had more success over at [the computer science stackexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com) but we'll see